# How to choose the best tech stack for an application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, architecture

I wanted to start a full stack project, with all the tech stacks in the market i am confused to which one should i pick. I know reactjs in frontend, nodejs and a little bit of django in backend.

1. First should i use Reactjs or any other frontend framework which is a single page application so all the JS code will execute from frontend or should i use that or Nextjs which does the server side rendering so in the browser we reduce the execution of js. If i stick with Nextjs then suppose i wanted to create a mobile app for my project can i use the nextjs for that or should i shift the code entirely

2)Does backend language really matter, if matters which language should i use and If it doesn’t matter then in nodejs which server framework should i pick(ex: expressjs)

3. Should I go with server or serverless while creating the api then it does not matter with the framework(because lately I have seen many realtime apps backend code is entirely wrriten by serverless functions using cloud)

4)tell me some of the important things i should use in a realtime app like docker, Kubernetes, load balancer, and any other things you might think this should be present in the full stack app

if you know any blogs or articles about choosing the architecture for ur project comment down.

Comment: Please see the help center article on [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. This isn't a bad question in and of itself, but it isn't appropriate for this site for a few reasons (requires opinion based answers, multiple questions at once)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very opinion and experience based question that cannot be answered as you are asking it (and is technically out of scope in stackoverflow). I will try to help as much as possible anyway.

In general many different stacks are viable and in order to be productive it is more important that you are experienced in what you decide to use. This is because most technologies have pitfalls that can only be avoided by knowing them / experience.

1. Besides the frontend technologies/frameworks you listed there are many others. Having some experience with React-Native as well, my personal current favorites would be Angular and Flutter (both Google technologies) for web/apps.
2. It does and it doesn't matter. Without knowing your specific requirements no recommendation can be given though. As a general hint I recommend to use a language that your developers love - There is usually a reason for it. [See the 2021 Stackoverflow Developer Survey.](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted)
3. Server vs. Serverless is mostly a business decision and you have to model your costs including hosting / development / maintenance efforts vs. usage models. Another aspect in this decision is time-to-market pressure since Serverless may be a bit faster to finish in some scenarios.
4. This cannot be answered without knowing the details and requirements of your project. Recommendations could be from hosting a static single web page in a S3 bucket to running your own fleet of (cloud-)-bare-metal clusters or buying a supercomputer.